# Codeigniter multiple user login

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a codeigniter application where students can see their yearly championship information, results and much more. We have yearly registrations for championship therefore students have different id and password for each year and I need to display a different interface to them.

I tried to create a subfolder for all 2020 controllers and views but I am not sure about how to route:
Example :

```
www.abc.com/dashboard // for 2019

www.abc.com/2020/dashboard // for 2020 (But this approach having issue to pass parameter)
```

What is the correct approach to this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can use the user creation date to route to the corresponding interface.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a subfolder in the project structure does not influence the logic of your application. I would create only a single username and password for each user. You can keep track of what interface to use for them in the db and load it according to the logged user. Hope you got the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter does not support multiple subdirectory levels in your controller's directory, just one.

Please see this url.

[There is a way to extend the routing class to support this, check this blog entry.](https://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/)